# I cannot append a new text to the existin text in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql> update articlestat set usr_id="someone@gmail.com" where articleid=11;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> update articlestat set usr_id=usr_id+ ",some2@gmail.com" where artic
leid=11;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ',praveen2dj@gmail.com'
```

Help I'm stuck here, all i need is a way to append both the mail id in the same field.

```
Field Type
usr_id varchar(1024)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses the `concat()` function for concatenation. `+` is purely arthematic addition.

```
UPDATE articlestat 
SET usr_id = CONCAT(usr_id, ",some@gmail.com");
```

In the grand scheme of things, do you REALLY want to be subverting the purpose of a relational data by storing what looks to be CSV data in a single field? That's horribly bad table design in almost all standard usage cases.

Answer (score 0):

ON my server:

```
UPDATE test SET uname= CONCAT(uname, ",some@gmail.com")
```

So your query will be:

```
UPDATE articlestat 
SET usr_id = CONCAT(usr_id, ",some@gmail.com");
```

The reference to the plus symbol is for mathmatical queries.

```
update Test SET ID=`ID`+2;
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concate string in mysql then use [concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function ...

```
update articlestat set usr_id=CONCAT(usr_id, ",some@gmail.com")
where articleid=11;
```